# Monitor data changes in SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to send message or http request or send notification when SQL Azure data changes or when new data is inserted? I would like to send message/ http request/ notification to a non .NET web application. I have done that invoke an application of Tomcat server by send a http request from local SQL server when there is data change, but I can't with SQL Azure.

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is ok to talk about our own [Cotega service](http://www.cotega.com).  IF you are interested in a finished solution for this, we are just finishing off the work to allow people to send Email and SMS notifications messages based on changes within their SQL Azure database so it would be interesting to see if we could extend this to suit your needs to call a .NET web app.  Feel free to contact me [from here](http://www.cotega.com/Home/support) if you are interested.